# Using reflections with Java Web Start

Tags: java, classpath, java-web-start

I want to use reflection to get all classes that are subclass of a specific class. We already use Guava and the `ClassPath` is not working because it tries to traverse up the in the ClassLoader and because of security the top level classloader in the JWS does not allow to trick with the classpath. I do not want to use libraries like `reflections` because of transitive dependencies.

Is there any simple solution for getting a list of subclasses of a given class when running with Java Web Start?

Comment: Not sure if it would give you the same problem, but have you tried http://www.eclecticlogic.com/2014/09/01/classpath-scanning/

Comment: *"I want to use reflection to get all classes that are subclass of a specific class."*  Why?  This has the distinct whiff of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I do not want to hardcode  each subclass, because of the frequent changes.

Comment: Why does the app. *need* a list of these sub-classes?